# I want to test whether the try catch block in my method is working or not

Tags: java, android-studio, testing, junit, try-catch

The below method is a method in my logic class that removes the required index from the list. I made an exception class so it handles an empty list or a list that will not have this index

```java
public class LogicClass{

public void removeThisObject (ArrayList<ThisObject> thisObjList, int index){

  try{
    if(thisObjList.size() < (index+1)) throw new MyException ("this list is empty or does not have this index");

    thisObjList.remove(index);
  }catch(MyException me){
    me.getMessage();
  }
}

}
```

Now Im trying to test this method in my JUnit tests class and I would like to INTENTIONALLY trigger the exception just to see whether the exception is not working or not

```java
public class Testing extends TestCase {

 public void testRemoveObj() {

        System.out.println("Checking if obj is being removed");

        LogicClass logicClass = new LogicClass();

        //ThisObject thisObj = new ThisObject();

        //INTENTIONALLY GIVING AN EMPTY LIST FOR THE METHOD TO PROCESS
        ArrayList<ThisObj> emptyList = new ArrayList<ThisObj>();
        try{
            //INTENTIONALLY GIVING INDEX 3 FOR AN EMPTY LIST
            logicClass.removeThisObject(3,emptyList);
            fail("Exception was not caught");

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught successfully");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("Removal was processed successfully. End of Test\n");

    }
}
```

But instead the method just .... works. The exception works fine as when i comment it out in the logic the JUnit throws an IndexOutOfBoundException, when uncommented it just gives me the output:

```
Checking if ingredient is being removed
Removal was processed successfully. End of Test
```

I apologize if i missed any brackets here and there. I really hope the code was typed out correctly to follow. Im hoping that you get the jist of it.

So all in all I am trying to purposely trigger the exception in the tests so to see whether the exception was properly implemented or not. Would appreciate any help.

Thank you !!!

Comment: You made some mistakes while trying to create a minimal reproducible example. Right now `removeThisObject` method is an instance method, not `static`, but you call it as a static method. Also, the arguments order is different, in the definition you have (list, index), in the call you use (index, list). Also, consider use assertThrows in JUnit to check for expected exception: [examples here](https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/expected-exception-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `junit` without `assertThrows`:

```
@Test
void test_throwExceptionWithoutAssertThrows() {
    try {
     // trigger exception
    } catch(MyException ex) { // Catch your specified exception
        ...
        assertStatements      // optional
        return;               // Stop execution at this point.
    }
    fail(); // we didn't catch, assert and return. Something went wrong.
}
```

Using `junit5` you can assert Exceptions with the `assertThrows(< TargetedException >.class, lambdaExpression)` like this:

```
@Test
void whenRemoveThisObjectCalled_thenMyExceptionThrown() {

    LogicClass logicClass = new LogicClass();
    assertThrows(MyException.class, () -> {
        List<Integer> emptyList = Collections.emptyList();
        logicClass.removeThisObject(1, emptyList);

    });
}
```

*Explanation*:
After your try-catch block executed, Exception or not, the program will continue. That is why you will see your "was successful" output, even if your desired Exception was thrown. If you know which scenario of exception throwing you want to test, it's not a good idea to "test try-catch in general", because we can assume that try-catch will work. Instead you can test, if your Exception is thrown under specified circumstances (see code above).

Comment: Is it possible to do this in Junit3 ~ Im not sure whats the issue with my android studio but whenever I try changing my tests to Junit5 it provides me with a whole bunch of errors.

But highly appreciate the quick response. THANK YOU !!!

Answer (score 0):

about your line :
**So all in all I am trying to purposely trigger the exception in the tests so to see whether the exception was properly implemented or not. Would appreciate any help.**

you can trigger the catch by this code :

```
if(true){
            Exception exception = new Exception();
            throw exception;
        }
```

for your function it will be like :

```
public class Testing extends TestCase {
        
    public void testRemoveObj() {

        System.out.println("Checking if obj is being removed");

        LogicClass logicClass = new LogicClass();

        //ThisObject thisObj = new ThisObject();

        //INTENTIONALLY GIVING AN EMPTY LIST FOR THE METHOD TO PROCESS
        ArrayList<ThisObj> emptyList = new ArrayList<ThisObj>();
        try{
            //INTENTIONALLY GIVING INDEX 3 FOR AN EMPTY LIST
            
            if(true){
                Exception exception = new Exception();
                throw exception;
            }
            
            logicClass.removeThisObject(3,emptyList);
            fail("Exception was not caught");

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught successfully");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("Removal was processed successfully. End of Test\n");

    }
}
```

this code will trigger an exception so you will be able to test your catch methods

Comment: This doesn't test whether `LogicClass#removeThisObject` throws the correct Exception for the estimated Exception-throwing test parameters. And it still prints "Removal was processed successfully." even with a triggered exception.

Comment: try the next answer that i will post now

Answer (score 0):

try this answer will post the success when it done :

```
public class Testing extends TestCase {
    
public void testRemoveObj() {

    System.out.println("Checking if obj is being removed");

    LogicClass logicClass = new LogicClass();

    //ThisObject thisObj = new ThisObject();

    //INTENTIONALLY GIVING AN EMPTY LIST FOR THE METHOD TO PROCESS
    ArrayList<ThisObj> emptyList = new ArrayList<ThisObj>();
    try{
        //INTENTIONALLY GIVING INDEX 3 FOR AN EMPTY LIST
        
        if(true){
            Exception exception = new Exception();
            throw exception;
        }
        
        logicClass.removeThisObject(3,emptyList);
        fail("Exception was not caught");
        System.out.println("Removal was processed successfully. End of Test\n");

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception caught successfully");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    

}
}
```

Comment: Please do not spam answers. Edit your previous answer to reflect your current answer. Thank you. PS: Your code still does not call `removeThisObject()` as it throws an exception beforehand.

Comment: sorry about that i will edit instead of add a new answer